# New to Programming: Output in a Recursive Function

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to figure out the following outputs

```
whoknows(2) = 
whoknows(15) = 
whoknows(-3) =  


void whoknows(const int x) {
    if (x < 2) { 
        print(x);
    } else {
        const int y = x / 2;
        whoknows(y);
        print(x % 2);
    }
}
```

I am not sure if I have the right answer,here is my understanding of this function.

The function whoknows (const int x)” is being declared as return type void, which means that the function will not return a value. The term (const int x) denotes that the changes are not going to extend past the local variable in the function. This is a recursive function because it calls itself in the function. The base condition of the recursion is x < 2. It uses the if…else construct as conditional statements to execute the code. Here, x will be passed through the function, and if its value is less than 2, then it will simply print its value. If not, then it will go through the else function where it will be divided by 2 and then the new value will be tested for the default condition. Default condition will keep being tested until it is satisfied, with every recursion dividing x by 2. Then x will go through print (x%2) and the remainder will always be x because by this point the number will always be less than two (base condition of the recursion.)

So far, I believe the results will be

whoknows @ 2 is 1,1
whoknows @ 15 is 1.875, 1.875
whoknows @ -3 is -3

Greatly appreciated if someone could let me know if my logic and results are OK and why. I'm having a hard time with these type of functions.

Comment: your logic is correct, you have only a problem with the second case. The line const int y = x / 2; is INTEGER division which means that you get only the integer part on division, example: 15 / 2 = 7 not 7.5

Comment: Thank you! I overlooked that. In that case, is whoknows(15)=  1,1 because only the integers are printed? Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

This function print the base 2 representation of the number. For example whoknows(15) prints 1111 and whoknows(13) prints 1101 and so on.
The logic behind it is simple, each time the method finds the rightmost bit (using x%2) and shift the number to right (using x/2) and repeating the procedure (by calling itself) until all bits are visited.